# How to Split csv file into multiple yaml files

Tags: csv, type-conversion, yaml, data-conversion, converters

I have a CSV file with a big list of upcoming events and i want to convert it to multiple yaml files so that each event has its own yaml file

CSV Example:

```
Event name, Description, date, start time, end time, address
Event 1, description 1, 2021/03/21, 12:00, 13:00, 4859 57th St NY
Event 2...
Event 3...
```

Desired output (one file for each event) - event1.yml:

```
Event name: Event 1
description: description 1
date: 2021/03/21
start time: 12:00
end time: 13:00
address: 4859 57th St NY
```

I haven't found solutions that split each row of the table into one separate files.